# Calculate Time Difference (in minutes) between days of week

Tags: python, datetime

Assume we have an empty list called `interval` and a list of lists named `shifts` that consist of: day_of_week, shift_start, and shift_end:

```
    interval = []
    shifts = [['Mon', '01:00', '22:00'], 
     ['Tue', '02:00', '23:00'],
     ['Wed', '01:15', '23:30'],
     ['Thu', '01:00', '21:00'],
     ['Fri', '02:30', '22:00'],
     ['Sat', '01:00', '21:00'],
     ['Sun', '03:00', '23:00']
    ]
```

The `interval` list will consist of the time differences (in minutes) between the shifts. As an example, the first element of `interval` will be the time difference between `'Mon', '22:00'` and `'Tue', '02:00'` which is `240` and the last element will be time difference between `'Sun', '23:00'` and `'Mon','01:00'` which is `120`

This is my code:

```
interval = []
start_time = []
end_time = []

for each in shifts:       
    start_time.append([each[0],each[1]])
    end_time.append([each[0],each[2]])

    start_val = ','.join([each[0], each[1]])
    start_time.append(start_val)
    end_val = ','.join([each[0], each[2]])
    end_time.append(end_val)

for i in range(len(shifts)):
    t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time[i],'%a').strftime()
    if(i < len(shifts)-1):
        t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time[i+1], '%a,%H:%M')
    else:
        t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time[0], '%a,%H:%M')
    delta = int((t1-t2).total_seconds()/60)
    interval.append(delta)
```

The problem is, the program ignore the day_of_week, so it assume the `t1` and `t2` were on the same day. So in my program, the first element of interval is `1320` which is `22` hours.

Need help to solve the problems. If my whole code is wrong or inconvenient please provide the best way to solve it.

Comment: Isn't Monday to Tuesday also 240 minutes not 480?  4 hours difference x 60 minutes?

Comment: Your input data is ambiguous. There is no way for Python (or anyone!) to know the difference in time between a Tuesday and a Friday. Which Tuesday? Which Friday? You'll have to implement that logic yourself, instead of relying on strptime.

Comment: Your code gives traceback like this. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sworks/try.py", line 28, in <module>
    t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time[i],'%a').strftime()
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list

Comment: Are these days in the same week? Python date time works on full dates and times, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would help probably

```
from datetime import datetime
formattime = datetime.strptime

interval = []
shifts = [['Mon', '01:00', '22:00'], 
 ['Tue', '02:00', '23:00'],
 ['Wed', '01:15', '23:30'],
 ['Thu', '01:00', '21:00'],
 ['Fri', '02:30', '22:00'],
 ['Sat', '01:00', '21:00'],
 ['Sun', '03:00', '23:00']
]
```

This appending here, we can call it a small hacky preprocessing.

```
shifts.append(shifts[0])
```

Method get_delta returns timedelta of two datetime params.

```
def get_delta(day1, day2):
    day, start, end, n_day, n_start, n_end = day1 + day2
    return formattime(n_day + n_start, '%a%H:%M') - formattime(day + end, '%a%H:%M')
```

Enumerating list provides you with index and the value which are unpacked as i, day1. And further there is a condition for end case. Day2 is taken by next index.

```
for i, day1 in enumerate(shifts):
    if i+1 == len(shifts):
        break
    day2 = shifts[i+1]
    delta = get_delta(day1, day2).seconds / 60
    interval.append(delta)
print(interval)
```

Result (in Minutes):

```
 [240, 135, 90, 330, 180, 360, 120]
```

Comment: could you explain what happen in get_delta function?

Comment: get_delta by its name returns delta of two datetimes. 
The first line appends two lists and unpacks into 6 variables. 
And further second line returns delta of two datetimes which we get from formattime.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the start times and the end times to epoch (which is basically a number), and then simply calculate the difference.

This difference will be in seconds (or ms, depending upon implementation), which you can further convert to seconds/minutes/hours as per your requirement.

Epoch is basically used for storing the date, but since they are not very important to you (as in Monday 18th and Monday 25th is same), just take a random date and assign epoch to start and end times. Since it's more or less a standard thing, there will be a lot of libraries to help you out.

So

```
start_time.append([(somedate day)+ each[0],(somedate + day) + each[1]])
end_time.append([(somdate + day) +each[0],(somedate + day)each[2]])
```

...

```
t1 = int(datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 1 1970' + end_time[i],yourFormat))
t2 = int(datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 2 1970' + start_time[i+1], yourFormat))
```

This difference will give you expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Choose some random dates that fall on Sunday-Saturday

```
import datetime
sun = datetime.datetime(2018,2,18)
mon = datetime.datetime(2018,2,19)
tue = datetime.datetime(2018,2,20)
wed = datetime.datetime(2018,2,21)
thu = datetime.datetime(2018,2,22)
fri = datetime.datetime(2018,2,23)
sat = datetime.datetime(2018,2,24)

day_of_week = {'sun':sun,'mon':mon,'tue':tue, 'wed':wed,
               'thu':thu,'fri':fri, 'sat':sat}
```

Use a timedelta object to get the *next* monday

```
next_week = datetime.timedelta(days=7)

shifts = [['Mon', '01:00', '22:00'], ['Tue', '02:00', '23:00'],
          ['Wed', '01:15', '23:30'], ['Thu', '01:00', '21:00'],
          ['Fri', '02:30', '22:00'], ['Sat', '01:00', '21:00'],
          ['Sun', '03:00', '23:00']]
```

Walk through the shifts and make datetime.datetime objects of the start and end times be combining the dates previously created with the shift times

```
dt_shifts = []
for day, start, end in shifts:
    hh, mm = map(int, start.split(':'))
    start = datetime.datetime.combine(day_of_week[day.lower()], datetime.time(hh, mm))
    hh, mm = map(int, end.split(':'))
    end = datetime.datetime.combine(day_of_week[day.lower()], datetime.time(hh, mm))
    dt_shifts.append((day, start, end))
```

Get the start and end times for adjacent shifts, subtract and print

```
for (day0,start0,end0), (day1,start1,end1) in zip(dt_shifts, dt_shifts[1:]):
    dt = start1 - end0
    print(f'{day0} - {day1} | {dt.seconds / 60}')
```

Add a week to Monday and use it for the last interval

```
day0,start0,end0 = day1,start1,end1
day1, start1, end1 = dt_shifts[0][0],dt_shifts[0][1] + next_week, dt_shifts[0][2] + next_week
print(f'{day0} - {day1} | {dt.seconds / 60}')
```

---

```
>>>   
Mon - Tue | 240.0
Tue - Wed | 135.0
Wed - Thu | 90.0
Thu - Fri | 330.0
Fri - Sat | 180.0
Sat - Sun | 360.0
Sun - Mon | 360.0
>>>
```